# Prompt for password and validate on specific page in Angular 8 application

Tags: angular, passwords, angular8

There are multiple pages in the application and now it is required to add a password prompt on selecting a specific link.

Basically the prompt appears after the page content loading initiated. We just want to validate it against a pre-determined password (static password declared in .TS file in background)

what is the best approach to do this?.

Comment: Never store passwords in UI.

Comment: this is internal to our team only. Hence NO strict restriction on security.

Comment: You can create [Auth guards](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) for all the pages that needs authenticition. If user is not authenticated redirect to login component and get him authenticated.

Comment: agreed, but with the authorized user also, it shd ask for a password. That is what we needed.

Comment: Then it's much more easy make the Auth guards just ask for password every time instead of creating and managing auth session